# calculating price with two values js with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

thanks to ph1409 I got to this solution   https://jsfiddle.net/poojjaval/a9u4mkwy/7
but i have been trying to make this script work with PHP and MySQLi, for example, setting the type of gender and weight range from a database and loading them to this script, but nothing I do seems to be working . can anyone point me on the right direction?

```
function Ticket(gender, weight) {
  this.gender = gender;
  this.weight = weight;
}

Ticket.prototype.getPrice=function() {
  var price;

  if(this.gender === "male" && this.weight > 200){
    price=20;
  }
  else if(this.gender === "female" && this.weight > 200) {
    price=15;
  }
  else if(this.gender === "male" && this.weight <= 200) {
    price=10;
  }
  else if(this.gender === "female" && this.weight <= 200) {
    price=7;
  }

  return price;
}

$("select").change(function() {
  var genderOptions = [];

  $("select option:selected").each(function() {
    genderOptions.push($(this).text() + " ");
  });

  var newTicket = new Ticket($("#gender").val(),$('#weight').val());
  var multiplyVal = newTicket.weight * newTicket.getPrice();

  $("#yourTicket").text("Gender: " + newTicket.gender + " Weight: " + 
  newTicket.weight + " $" + newTicket.getPrice().toFixed(2) + " and your 
  multiplied value is " + multiplyVal);
});
```

Comment: How are you pulling data from php mySQL? Are you echoing it to the screen or are you using ajax?

Comment: is there any way to call the data to the script